# Как установить аватар?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы бот "пикселизировал" аватар упомянутого человека. Вот мой код:

```py
@bot.command()
async def pixelate(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/canvas/pixelate') 
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)

    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9900, title = 'Пикселирование')
    embed.set_image(url = json_data['avatar']) 
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Но вот в чём проблема: когда я захожу на [этот сайт](https://some-random-api.ml/canvas/pixelate), то мне выводит вот такое:

> error "Missing avatar queries"

Если же я оставлю код таким, как я написал выше, то при использовании команды мне выводит вот такое:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'avatar'

И вот вопрос: как этот аватар установить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама ссылка, которую вы указали *(https://some-random-api.ml/canvas/pixelate)*, это URL для осуществления API-запроса к серверу. Адрес не предназначен для просмотра содержимого через какой-то графический интерфейс и ожидает от вас каких-либо входных данных на вход.

В данном случае - сервер вернул ошибку, так как не получил изображение для обработки.

---

В документации данного сервиса есть на 90% [**готовое решение**](https://some-random-api.ml/docs/examples/Python#canvas-endpoint-example), написанное сразу же на `Python` для библиотеки `discord-py`. Поиск инструкции или сразу готовых решений - это первое, что вам нужно было сделать при решении данной задачи.

В итоге из работы с сервисом, все, что осталось сделать - заменить адрес API-запроса из примера на пикселизацию изображения:

```py
@bot.command()
async def pixelate(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    if not user:
        user = ctx.author

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(f'https://some-random-api.ml/canvas/pixelate?avatar={user.avatar_url_as(format="png", size=1024)}') as trigImg:
            await session.close()
            embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9900, title = 'Пикселирование')
            embed.set_image(url = trigImg.url) 
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```